# cakephp linked data HABTM by JOIN need both related data?

Tags: cakephp, join

This should be a simple Yes/No answer so here goes.

If I set a 3 tables, 2 typical recordsets and 1 that joins them by the id of the 2 tables, do I need the id from both tables in order to have an entry in the join table?

The scenario is a `Jobs` table and a `Parts` table linked by `JobsParts` table. But some parts are not in the Parts table, they are just freetext entries (so as to avoid stock control issues) belonging to a `Job`.

Hope this is enough to explain my question.

Thanks

BTW using CakePHP 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For database sanity, I'd say the join table 'jobs_parts' should have both IDs.

If you try entering free-form parts into the join table, you're not only going to increase the size of the join table, but you've effectively lost the ability to grow/expand - ie. what if you want to add a few more fields to this unknown part?  Or what if it turns out to be a part that you actually want in your normal parts table....  it just gets confusing.

There are other options for dealing with free-form parts vs actual parts...

- have a field in the parts table that's a tinyint(1) for whether or not it's a verified part
- OR make an UnknownParts model/table

In my opinion, go with what makes logical sense for ease of understanding and for future updates to your database/website...etc.  And IMO, adding a freeform part into the join table would not fit that bill.